# Device Administrator password

Tags: android

Is it possible to require a pass-code when the user tries to uncheck the app as an administrator under **Settings**->**Security**->**Device Administrators**?

This would add a roadblock to not easily allow the user to uninstall the app as they would first need to remove the admin privileges from the app (for which they would need to authenticate with a password) and then they could uninstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***This is not possible AFIK. This is right of user.***

You can show a dialog for confirmation about DE-activation of [Device Admin](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html), but neither [default device admin API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) gives you a way to show password dialog while DE-activating device admin, nor EDM APIs gives you the permission.

Although EDM APIs gives a way where you can block the DE-activation of Device administrator. So user can not uncheck a particular Device admin.

Comment: This is an enterprise API which is provided by manufacturer like Samsung, Motorola

Comment: Can you, please, give some link with example for samsung? Because I cannot find anything?

Comment: No Those are for corporate uses not for personal. If you want to use, you have to be a partner of Samsung :)

Answer (score 0):

---

It is possible, but you'd have to employ some pretty sketchy techniques to achieve that. For example, [Cerberus](https://www.cerberusapp.com/) has an option called "Protect device admin" which immediately locks your screen and asks for login and password as soon as you tap "Deactivate this device administrator".

I cannot recommend you do this though since it's considered to be malicious behavior. You should use corporate policies instead. AFAIK they've been implemented to newer versions of Android and are not tied to a specific manufacturer.